# Java .drawImage : How do I "unDraw" or delete a image?

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I need a certain image to be redrawn at different locations constantly as the program runs. So  I set up a while loop that should move an image across the screen, but it just redraws the image on top of itself over and over again. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to delete the old image before drawing it in a new location?

```
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("BeachRoad_double_size.png"));

    JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int num = 0;
            boolean fluff = true;
            while (fluff == true) {
            num = num + 1;
            g.drawImage(image, num, 0, null);
            if (num == 105) {
                fluff = false;
            }
            }
        }
    };


    frame.add(pane);
```

Comment: What you probably want to do is set up the `paintComponent` method to just draw at a give point and call `repaint()` from elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, this is not perminate code, I am just trying to figure out some things before moving on to write practical code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't code a loop in the paintComponent() method. The code will execute so fast that the image will only be painted in the final position, which in your case should be with an x position of 105.

Instead you need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation every 100 milliseconds or so. Then when the timer fires you update the x position and invoke repaint() on the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a while loop inside a `paintComponent` method is not the way to do it. Instead, there should be some setup like the following:

```
...
final int num = 0;
final JPanel pane;
Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        num++;
        pane.repaint();
    }
});
pane = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, num, 0, null);
    }
});

timer.start();
```

This will move the image ever 10 milliseconds, as specified in the Timer constructor.

Comment: @user2619934 You want to use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: 1- 10 milliseconds may be to short a time interval; 2- You should be passing "this" as the ImageObserver parameter of drawImage

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue people starting out in animation have, as I did. You can't 'remove an image' from the screen. However, you can repaint the entire screen, then redraw your image at a new location.

In psuedocode:

```
while (condition)
   background(white); //or whatever color your background is
   drawImage(x,y);
```

The code above clears the screen so it's safe for you to redraw your image. This effectively 'deletes' your image.

Edit: I didn't read your code, I just addressed your question. So other answers that fix your code are probably better than mine.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in a simple to understand general way.