# How do I display multiple Images on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've been trying to figure this out forever, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I would like to display more than one image on the screen in the same JPanel but for some reason, it only displays the last image from the paint component

I'm trying to make a fruit ninja style game and would like to draw the fruits out of the frame before animations take place.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
import javax.swing.*;//imports JPanel class
import java.awt.*;//imports the Graphics class

public class FruitNinja extends JPanel {

   private Image dojo;
   private Image apple;
   private Image orange;
   private Image pineapple;
   private Image strawberry;
   private Image banana;

   private Timer timer;
   private int x, y;

   public FruitNinja() { // a constructor to set up graphics windo
      super();
      setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      loadImage();
      x = 25;
      y = 25;


   }



   private void loadImage() {
      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Dojo.jpg");
      dojo = ii.getImage();

      ImageIcon oo = new ImageIcon("Orange.ico");
      orange = oo.getImage();

      ImageIcon ss = new ImageIcon("Strawberry.png");
      strawberry = ss.getImage();

      ImageIcon bb = new ImageIcon("Banana.png");
      banana = bb.getImage();

      ImageIcon pp = new ImageIcon("Pineapple.png");
      pineapple = pp.getImage();

      ImageIcon aa = new ImageIcon("Apple.png");
      apple = aa.getImage();


   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ // draw graphics in the panel

      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(dojo, 0,0, this);
      //draws out dojo


      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(apple, 0,0, this);

      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(orange, 0,0, this);

      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(pineapple, 0,0, this);

      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(banana, 0,0, this);

      super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
      g.drawImage(strawberry, 0,0, this);

      //draws out the fruits somewhere
   }

  /* 
   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      x += 5;
      y += 5;

      if (y > getHeight()) {
         y = 25;
         x = 25;
      }
      repaint();
   }
*/

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

      FruitNinja panel = new FruitNinja(); // window for drawing  
      JFrame f = new JFrame(); // the program itself
      f.setTitle("Fruit Ninja");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//when the X button is clicked, the program quits
      f.setSize(1280,800);//size of the frame
      Container pane = f.getContentPane();//pane refers to the interior of the JFrame

      FruitNinja p1 = new FruitNinja();

      pane.add(p1);//add the FacePanel object to the interior of the frame
      f.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Also unrelated to this current question, since I'm trying to make a `FruitNinja` like game, how do I make it so the code registers that my mouse is there(so it slices the fruit when my mouse hovers over the fruit)? is it mouseListenter?

Comment: The simplest solution is using an appropriate layout manager and `JLabel`s

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to understand why you're having the problem you're having

Comment: Done with this.

Comment: How do I close this thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to understand why you're having the problem you're having

One of the jobs that `paintComponent` does it prepares the `Graphics` context for painting of the component, it typically does this by filling it with the background color of the component

So based on you code, that would suggest you only need to call `paintComponent` once, at the start of the method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ // draw graphics in the panel

  super.paintComponent(g);// to make panel display correctly
  g.drawImage(dojo, 0,0, this);
  //draws out dojo
  g.drawImage(apple, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(orange, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(pineapple, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(banana, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(strawberry, 0,0, this);
  //draws out the fruits somewhere
}
```

So, now all the images should be painted, on top of each other

> Also unrelated to this current question, since I'm trying to make a FruitNinja game, how do I make it so the code registers that my mouse is there(so it slices the fruit when my mouse hovers over the fruit)? is it mouseListenter?

You're probably looking for a `MouseMotionListener`, have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! I really appreciate the information you've provided as well as the extra information to help a new programmer like me. Once again, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

You have extended `JPanel` and in that `JPanel` you have drawn in the same `x` and `y`, which is `0`. And also in the overridden `paintComponent()` method you are calling the `super` class method number of times. Because of this you can only see lastly drawn image.

Change this:

```
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(apple, 0,0, this);

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(orange, 0,0, this);

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(pineapple, 0,0, this);

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(banana, 0,0, this);

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(strawberry, 0,0, this);
```

To:

```
  super.paintComponent(g);

  g.drawImage(apple, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(orange, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(pineapple, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(banana, 0,0, this);
  g.drawImage(strawberry, 0,0, this);
```

Still you cannot see other images because all the images are in top of each other. To avoid this you can do something like this:

```
  super.paintComponent(g);

  g.drawImage(dojo, x,0, this);
  g.drawImage(apple, x,100, this);
  g.drawImage(orange, 300,100, this);
  g.drawImage(pineapple, x,300, this);
  g.drawImage(banana, 300,0, this);
  g.drawImage(strawberry, 300,300, this);
```

You can change `x` and `y` cordinate as you want. But still this is confuse and annoying also it is time consuming. Well, there is a better way to do this. That is [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Think of a way to use [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to your program. These link may help you:

- [how to use layout manager](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-layout-manager).
- [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html).
- [Oracle tute.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

In the last part of your question you mention about

> how do I make it so the code registers that my mouse is there

You need to get current position of pointer(`x` and `y`).

> is it mouseListenter?

No it is not unless you donot have many events. `mouseListenter` for mouse events (press, release, click, enter, and exit) on a component.

What you need is `MouseMotionListener` according to above statement. It is for mouse motion events on a component.

**UPDATE(according to the comment):**

> I'm not really sure how you use a MouseMotionListener? I've been able
>   to animate the fruit/images so it's flying around my frame now. How do
>   I use the MouseMotionListener to move that fruit off of the frame once
>   I hover over it?

*This is out of the scope of the question but as a help,*

Well, to this you have to add all the images into `JLabel`s otherwise you can add listener to the panel. Since there is multiple images you have to create labels. To do this I've created new method, Code should look like this:

```
public void moveImage(ImageIcon icon){
    JLabel dojoLabel = new JLabel();
    dojoLabel.setIcon(icon);
    this.add(dojoLabel);

    dojoLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt){
            dojoLabel.setLocation(0,0);
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

Now inside your `loadImage()` call this method parsing `ImageIcon`. Cannot add `Image` type to a `JLabel`. That's why you need to add `ImageIcon`.

```
private void loadImage() {
      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Dojo.jpg");
      dojo = ii.getImage();
      //.....
      //move method here
      moveImage(ii);
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the in detail reply. Thankfully, I was able to fix that problem I had by only calling super once and moving my fruits in different areas?  I'm not really sure how you use a MouseMotionListener? I've been able to animate the fruit/images so it's flying around my frame now. How do I use the MouseMotionListener to move that fruit off of the frame once I hover over it? I searched up MouseMotion Listener online and there is a tutorial, but I'm still unsure about it.

Comment: @Martin this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867537/java-drawimage-how-do-i-undraw-or-delete-a-image

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure how to use the MouseMotionListener???? Think what you linked me to was something about deleting images.

Comment: Did you mean move a image to a corner when hover?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to move an image off, just change where the location is. But I need something to initiate that, which is what MouseMotionListener needs to do? I suppose a boolean should do? The thing is, I'm not sure how. So if I hover over something, the image is then moved off the frame.

Comment: @Martin: Look at update section in answer. In that way you can move, delete or change image when hover.

Comment: I'm sorry about it, but I still don't understand what's happening(about JLabels,etc), I think it would be better if I just posted another question.

Comment: @Martin: Ask a new question

Comment: @Martin: We cannot teach you, only a solution and some description. You have to read a book or follow tutorial. this is my best!.